# Using tooltip which is not the standard

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im having MVC5 Application with bootstrap3 and I want to use tooltip which is not the standard like following which is simple one ,how can I do that?

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="some text">Tooltip on left</button>
```

For example how should I change the tool-tip background to blue and the text to white?

Comment: `[data-toggle="tooltip"] { /* rule here */ }` , use the regular syntax for attributes and/or not  their values

Comment: @GCyrillus-Not sure that I fully understand your suggestion,can you pls provide the example with the context to the post?

Comment: to change background, you need CSS , right ?  to change bg to the data-toggle with value tooltip, you need the selector that will do that. now add hover behind it .`[data-toggle="tooltip"]:hover { /* rule here */background:blue; }` This is basicly the rule you need . You should provide a well formed fiddle or codepen , so we get your point

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dzhrs if problem comes from a custom them , tell us/me

Comment: @GCyrillus-I try to run the codepen and currently there is button with the text of the tooltip blue with text in white but this is not what I need,I need any default button that open tooltip with blue background and white text...

Comment: it's an hint, what have you tried yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customize the tooltip styling with:

```
.custom-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: blue;
  }
.custom-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-arrow {
  border-right-color:blue;
    }
```

Having added the custom class to the trigger element:

```
<button data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" 
data-original-title="Tooltip on right" 
class="btn btn-default custom-tooltip">Blue Tootlip</button>
```

NOTE: to style the caret colour as well (which I assume you want to), you need to make sure to style **only** the corresponding `border-direction-color:blue`, otherwise it gets weird.

**Here's an example: http://www.bootply.com/dirAtPOnPa**

Answer (score 0):

To use the Bootstrap tooltip you don't set the "title" attribute, you set "tooltip":

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" 
    data-tooltip-placement="left" 
    data-tooltip="some text">Tooltip on left</button>
```

Comment: Thanks but i try it like follwoing and its not working (the tooltip)do I miss something       <input type="submit" value="Update" data-toggle="tooltip" data-tooltip-placement="left" data-tooltip="some text" class="btn btn-default btn-update" />

Comment: @mileyH Are you sure you have included the JS dependencies? You need to include either bootstrap.js or tooltip.js in your HTML file.

Comment: @Tyblitz Which are they,I have bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css